# R: How to find minimum of a variable when an attribute is not equal to own?

Tags: r

I have been trying to calculate the minimum of a variable with a condition. I have the following data:

```
Data
Date       Net Price 
2013-12-01  A   39  
2013-12-01  B   23  
2013-12-01  C   25  
2013-12-08  A   52  
2013-12-08  B   12  
2013-12-08  C   19  
2013-12-15  A   32  
2013-12-15  B   36  
2013-12-15  C   40
```

I want to add a column of min price against A which is Min(B,C) and against B which is Min(A,B) and so on for date.

```
Date       Net Price Min 
2013-12-01  A   39  23
2013-12-01  B   23  25
2013-12-01  C   25  23
2013-12-08  A   52  12
2013-12-08  B   12  19
2013-12-08  C   19  12
2013-12-15  A   32  36
2013-12-15  B   36  32
2013-12-15  C   40  32
```

Can someone help me find the minimum by a date when Network not equal to own.

Thanks

Comment: But I need the minimum value for a date against A with min(B,c) and against B it should be min(A,C) and so on.

Comment: I suggest you add the desired result to your post.  I am not sure what you are asking for.  Are you asking for the vector c(23,12,32)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use this:

```
f <- function(x){m <- min(x); ifelse(x==m, min(x[x>m]), m)}
within(Data, Min <- ave(Price, Date, FUN=f))
```

Result:

```
        Date Net Price Min
1 2013-12-01   A    39  23
2 2013-12-01   B    23  25
3 2013-12-01   C    25  23
4 2013-12-08   A    52  12
5 2013-12-08   B    12  19
6 2013-12-08   C    19  12
7 2013-12-15   A    32  36
8 2013-12-15   B    36  32
9 2013-12-15   C    40  32
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say this is the most elegant solution, but it works.

```
data <- read.table(text='Date       Net Price 
2013-12-01  A   39  
2013-12-01  B   23  
2013-12-01  C   25  
2013-12-08  A   52  
2013-12-08  B   12  
2013-12-08  C   19  
2013-12-15  A   32  
2013-12-15  B   36  
2013-12-15  C   40  ',header=TRUE)

sp <- split(data,data$Date)
mindrop1 <- function(j) sapply(1:nrow(j),function(i) min(j$Price[-i]))
data$Min <- unlist(lapply(sp, mindrop1))

> data
        Date Net Price Min
1 2013-12-01   A    39  23
2 2013-12-01   B    23  25
3 2013-12-01   C    25  23
4 2013-12-08   A    52  12
5 2013-12-08   B    12  19
6 2013-12-08   C    19  12
7 2013-12-15   A    32  36
8 2013-12-15   B    36  32
9 2013-12-15   C    40  32
```

Comment: Thanks, this is quite helpful for now.